# Problem with pass props from an js array to MUI Item as an link | Type Error: (items.map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

as I mention in Topic

I got a problem with set a href link and passing it to the mobile, desktop menu. Never had this issue with semantic HTML elements, but I always struggle when I try to pass it to react components for pre-prepared elements.

Did anyone struggle with that before?
Maybe can someone share with me any tutorial or docs on how to inject an array in this kind of element as a map.

Here's the pure code copied
from the newest MUI React Library **with added by me array named [items]**

```
// array
const [items] = ([
  {
    name: 'John',
    href: 'https://google.com'
  }
]);

function DrawerAppBar(props) {
  const { window } = props;
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  // mobile menu
  const drawer = (
    <Box onClick={handleDrawerToggle} sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ my: 2 }}>
        Logo
      </Typography>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {items.map(item => (
          <ListItem key={item} disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href={item.href} sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );

  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  // desktop menu
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <AppBar component="nav">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { sm: 'none' } }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            component="div"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
          >
            Logo
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}>
            {items.map(item => (
              <Button key={item.name} sx={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                {item.name}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Box component="nav">
        <Drawer
          container={container}
          variant="temporary"
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
          sx={{
            display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' },
            '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
          }}
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

DrawerAppBar.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  window: PropTypes.func,
};

export default DrawerAppBar;
```

And here's the error from Console in Browser

```
Navbar.jsx:44 Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
    at DrawerAppBar (Navbar.jsx:44:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
```

Comment: looks like more a typo error. You are setting `const [items] = ([...`, try change it to `const items = ([...`

Comment: You are restructuring the first value from the array into the items variable, which makes it an object, not an array.